# How to force li elements to scroll horizontally and should be able to accommodate all the li elements in only one single line using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the default scrolling of li elements from vertical to horizontal.
I am able to do this but its coming as a list of elements in a line then another list of elements below it.
But I want all the list to be in one single line regardless of number of li elements.

Code in HTML:

```
<div class="imageGallery">
       <ul>
           <li><img src="img01.png"/></li>
           <li><img src="img02.png"/></li>
           <li><img src="img03.png"/></li>
           <li><img src="img04.png"/></li>
           .....
           .....
       </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.imageGallery {
    overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;

}   
        ul {
        width: 1500px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

The output is coming as a horizontal scrollbar with list of images in a line then list of elements below it and so on.
How can I make it all to come in single line?

Thanking you all for the help.

Comment: Set a specific width and height on the desired elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I understand well you want all li elements to stay in one line. put this in your css

```
.imageGallery ul{
    white-space: nowrap
} 
.imageGallery li{ 
    display:inline-block 
}
```

Comment: After modifying a bit I got it.
Please find the modified code below:

.imageGallery ul{
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 572px;
} 
.imageGallery li{ 
    display:inline 
}

Comment: Thanks for this `display:inline-block` That was the rule i was missing!  http://plnkr.co/edit/D2BKbQJsqAWJFN2byrth?p=preview